# Couldn't sort the rank or string by using java sorting algorithm

Tags: java

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Card{

private String rank;
private String suit;
private Card[] deck;
private int currentCard;
private static final int NCARDS = 52;
private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();
private static String[] ranks ={ "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", 
        "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K","A"};
private static String[] suits = { "Spades", "Heart", "Clubs", "Diamond" };

public Card(String rank,String suit)
{
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public Card()
{

    deck = new Card[ NCARDS ];
    for ( int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++ )
        deck[ count ] = new Card( ranks[ count % 13 ], suits[ count / 13 ]         
}

public void shuffle()
{
    for ( int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++ ){
        int second = randomNumbers.nextInt( NCARDS );
        Card temp = deck[ first ];
        deck[ first ] = deck[ second ];
        deck[ second ] = temp;
    }
}

public String getSuit()
{

    return this.suit;
}

public String getRank()
{
    return this.rank;
}

public Card dealCard()
{
    if(currentCard < deck.length)
        return deck[currentCard++];
    else
        return null;
}

public String toString(){
    return getRank() + " of " + getSuit();
}
```

//my sorting algorithm, couldn't work, still remain the same output

```
public void sortbyRank()
{
    //how to compare suit since club is higher than diamond

    for(int i=0; i<deck.length-1; ++i)
    {
        int min = i;
        for(int j =i +1; j<deck.length ; ++j){
            if(deck[j].getRank().compareTo(deck[i].getRank()) < 0)
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        Card temp = deck[min];
        deck[min] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;
    }

}
```

all function works, but could sort after i compile the code, i need to compare to suit first then rank but i couldn't done the suit since the "Club" is greater than "Diamond" in this category.

Comment: user this into your if condition        Card temp = deck[min];
        deck[min] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;.

Comment: Hint: look into the mental "model" you are building. The Card class should be about **one** card. You better add  a **Game** class, too - that would be the correct abstraction to know/deal/sort your **deck**. Or do you think that each card that you hold with your hand also does contain the whole card deck in the real world?!